# Django ImportError when attempting to use a setting in a settings directory

Tags: django, settings, importerror

Alright, so I've been wrestling with this problem for a good two hours now.

I want to use a settings module, local.py, when I run my server locally via this command:

```
$ python manage.py runserver --settings=mysite.settings.local
```

However, I see this error when I try to do this:

```
    ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite.settings.local' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named base
```

This is how my directory is laid out:

```
├── manage.py
├── media
├── myapp
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
└── mysite
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── settings
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   ├── local.py
    │   └── local.pyc
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

Similar questions have been asked, but their solutions have not worked for me.

One suggestion was to include an initialization file in the settings folder, but, as you can see, this is what I have already done.

Need a hand here!

Comment: Can you check this commands output and verify if settings.local file is part of that path - >>> import sys
>>> for path in sys.path: print path

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the local.py module imports from base.py, you probably have something like:

```
from base import *
```

at the top of your local settings.

But the base.py settings module is not there, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that django is not finding "mysite.settings.local" package because it is not in your `PYTHONPATH`.

You have to add sys.path in your manage.py file, following should work for you :-

> sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(`__file__`)))